# How to count total no. of TD tags from specific TR tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I have one simple table and I want to get count of each TR and it's TDs , But my code is returning me total TD count of page.

```
List<WebElement> TRcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println(TRcount.size());
if(TRcount.size()>0)
{
    for(int i=0;i<TRcount.size();i++)
    {
        List<WebElement> TDcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        System.out.println("First TR Contains: " + TDcount.size());            
    }
}
```

**Table Code :**

```
<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>PREVIOUS TEST</th><th>CURRENT TEST</th></tr>
<tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td><td>Row:1 Cell:2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td><td>Row:2 Cell:2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want code which return me like **1st TR contains 2 TD** , **2nd TR contains 2 TD**.

My current code returns me **total 4 TD.** But I want TR wise TD count.

Comment: Try initializing TDCount as follows: `List<WebElement> TDcount = TRCount.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));`

Comment: @heenenee - thanks buddy , it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `findElements()` on the individual WebElement of the `<tr>` tags.

```
List<WebElement> TRcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(WebElement e : TRcount) {
    List<WebElement> TDcount = e.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    System.out.println("First TR Contains: " + TDcount.size());
}
```

OR

```
for(int i=0; i<TRcount.size(); i++) {
    List<WebElement> TDcount = TRCount.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    System.out.println("First TR Contains: " + TDcount.size());
}
```

**EDIT:**

For fetching text from the individual `<td>` tags.

```
for(int i=0; i<TRcount.size(); i++) {
    List<WebElement> TDcount = TRCount.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    System.out.println("First TR Contains: " + TDcount.size());

    // Fetch text from individual '<td>' tags
    for(int j=0; j<TDcount.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(TDcount.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , count is working but getting null exception when I try to get data of TD , I tried : `TDcount.get(i).getText();` I want to get text of TDs one by one.

Comment: @HelpingHands - You need to use another loop to iterate over the `<td>` tags. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying without loop and it was mistake. Thanks again.